# Java XML api removes whitespace before self closing tag

Tags: java, xml

I've XML file which contains only one element

```
<Message>
    <Location URI ="XXX:XXX:XXX" />
</Message>
```

I want to read and print same XML using Java, but after print it loses white space before />

```
<Message>
    <Location URI ="XXX:XXX:XXX"/>
</Message>
```

I have tried different configuration of DocumentBuilderFactory and Transformer but the result is same.

Any Idea?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document requestDocument = builder.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/message-template.xml"));

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(requestDocument);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(domSource, result);

System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: What is the way you read and print the file?

Comment: Why is the space relevant for you? Both XML code describe the same document.

Comment: @Nikolas I've edited my question. Now you can see code snippet

Comment: "Any Idea?" Several. Stop caring if the space is there. Don't read and print, just print. Write your own set of XML tools that don't care about the XML standards and act as if the space you're concerned about matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(requestDocument);
...
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
```

You transform a `DOMSource` into a `StreamResult` . A `DOMSource` is not not a textual representation of the XML file but a Document Object Model (DOM) tree.
So whitespaces that are not considered as relevant to represent the content of the tree are not kept in the `DOMSource` :

```
URI ="XXX:XXX:XXX" />
                  |-------> not preserved
```

Most of APIs to represent and manipulate XML work in this way.
If you need to keep not significant whitespace in your result, you should probably do yourself the parsing of the XML file.